Looking for info on the history of Spanish
I am wondering what kind of influence Persian had on the development of Spanish. I have discovered that the Matar root (kill) that helps make the word "matador" comes from:

Spanish, literally ‘killer’, from matar ‘to kill’, from Persian māt ‘dead’;

is that a usual path for Spanish, tracing back to Persian?

This needs to have more detail to be answered. Are you asking whether there are any other words of Persian origin in Spanish? Are you asking whether the grammatical structure of Spanish was influenced by Persian grammar?

Ese término vino del latín vulgar, no del persa. Y casi no hay palabras tomadas del persa, simplemente son cogmados por ser las dos lenguas indoeuropeas.

Please post this on META.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on META.

According to the DRAE, matar comes from Latin mactare.
According to wikipedia, mactare means


to reward, honor
to punish, trouble
to offer, sacrifice, immolate
(Medieval Latin) to break

5. (Medieval Latin) to kill

So, I think that it's a coincidence or that both Latin and Persian share the same Indoeuropean root. In any case, it seems that Spanish didn't incorporate that word during the VIII century from the Moors.

Persian is classified as an indoeuropean language.  So it's no surprise that they share the same roots.

@PeterM Sure, let's say that Spanish and current Persian share a common ancestor but there is no direct relation between them in the case of matar.

(I started writing this as a comment but it morphed into an answer.)
It's well known that the Spanish language is greatly influenced by Arabic due to the invasion by the Moors in the 6th century (See here and here for example).
But in the 10th century there was already a Persian diaspora.  This link touches a little on Persians in Spain.

Razi wrote in the 10th century that some Iranians had already settled
in Al-Andalus

And Andalucia was one of the main bullfighting areas of Spain.  This could explain the roots of the word Matador (but I'm not an expert).
So it is quite likely that some words in Spanish had Persian roots. However, I don't think that  Persian was major contributor to the language.  This page on The influences on on the Spanish Language barely acknowledges Iranian only in this section.

(Empecé a escribir esto como un comentario, pero lo cambió a una respuesta)
Es bien sabido que el idioma español fue muy influenciado por el árabe debido a la invasión de los moros en el siglo VI. (Mira aquí y aquí por ejemplo).
Pero en el siglo X ya había una diáspora persa.  Este enlace aborda un poco el tema de los persas en España.

Razi escribió en el siglo X que algunos iraníes ya se habían
establecido en Al-Andalus.

Y Andalucía fue una de las principales zonas taurinas de España.  Esto podría explicar las raíces de la palabra Matador (pero no soy un experto).
Por lo tanto, es muy probable que algunas palabras del español tuvieran raíces persas. Sin embargo, no creo que el idioma persa fuera un contribuidor importante al idioma.  Esta página sobre Las influencias en la lengua española (pero la página es en inglés) apenas reconoce a los iraníes sólo en esta sección.

El libro “Las palabras de origen persa en el español“ contiene 244 palabras de origen persa.
Ejemplos: afgani, alcoba, almizcle, amazona, arsénico, auge, ayatolá, azucena, baldaquín, bronce, cahíz, carmesí, caviar, circón, dado, guitarra, maniqueo, mielga, ormesí, pachá, paraíso, pato, persiana, rosa, tigre.
https://colombiacuriosa.blogspot.com/2019/07/palabras-de-origen-persa.html

Hmmm .. Pero es obvio que "alcoba" es una palabra árabe porque utiliza el prefijo "al" que no se usa en persa.  Y la lengua árabe influenciada la lengua persa. Mira aquí

El diccionario de la RAE menciona sobre la palabra alcoba: Del ár. hisp. alqúbba, este del ár. clás. qubbah, y este del pelvi gumbad 'cúpula [de un templo del fuego]'. El pelvi es una escritura antigua del idioma persa.

HISTORIA
Para los etimologistas, la lengua persa es muy interesante porque existen escritos mucho más antiguos en ella que en árabe.
El origen de la escritura árabe se remonta al siglo VI d.C., mientras que se han encontrado escritos de los persas en cuneiforme, la escritura más antigua conocida en el mundo.
La inscripción en Behistun, realizada alrededor del 515 a. C., es una especie de piedra de Rosetta, que ha permitido su desciframiento.
El diccionario persa consta de 343.466 palabras y el idioma persa es capaz de formar 225 millones de palabras, porque el idioma hace un uso extensivo de técnicas de construcción de palabras, como la afijación y la composición, para derivar nuevas palabras a partir de raíces.
El persa ha influido en el vocabulario de otras lenguas, especialmente el árabe.
La conquista árabe de Irán duró dos siglos, desde el siglo VII hasta el siglo IX d. C. Durante este período, se importaron palabras árabes al idioma persa y varias de ellas se incorporaron al árabe.
El primer contacto para adoptar los arabismos en el español fue entre el siglo VIII y el siglo XI, "con la convivencia muy fuerte entre dos lenguas, el protocastellano/roman-andalusí, romance de Al-Ándalus muy temprano, y el árabe andalusí".
El segundo contacto es durante las conquistas de los reinos cristianos a los musulmanes, donde hay una nueva convivencia de las lenguas árabe y castellano.
PALABRAS DE ORIGEN PERSAS
El libro “Las palabras de origen persa en el español” contiene 244 palabras de origen persa.
Ejemplos: afgani, alcoba, almizcle, amazona, arsénico, auge, ayatolá, azucena, baldaquín, bronce, cahíz, carmesí, caviar, circón, dado, guitarra, maniqueo, mielga, ormesí, pachá, paraíso, pato, persiana, rosa, tigre.
https://colombiacuriosa.blogspot.com/2019/07/palabras-de-origen-persa.html
ORIGEN DE LA PALABRA MATAR
La única certeza sobre el origen de la palabra matar, en la que coinciden todos los etimologistas reputados, es que hasta la fecha nadie lo sabe.
En https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/aih/pdf/14/aih_14_1_025.pdf, Steven Dworkin de la Universidad de Michigan, discute y refuta las versiones existentes y añade la suya propia que, según él mismo, tampoco puede probarse.
Concluye con esta constatación:
“La génesis de matar sirve para ilustrar una vez más la relación entre la etimología y el estudio de procesos fonológicos diacrónicos y los peligros de acercarse a un problema etimológico con una idea previa fija.”
